# socket or http, which is better option to serve images in node js?

Tags: node.js, image, http, stream, socket.io

I just want to know what the best way (most optimal, less expensive) to serve images with nodejs, using HTTP or sockets? (maybe socket.io)

I read here that the best way to serve an imagen with HTTP is doing a streaming

```
fs.createReadStream(file, {
        'flags': 'r',
        'encoding': 'binary',
        'mode': '0666',
        'bufferSize': 4096
    }).addListener( "data", function(chunk) {
        response.write(chunk, 'binary');
    }).addListener( "close",function() {
        response.end();
    });
```

and with socket? which is the best way?

Thanks

Comment: what about save those file into a server and then using web-sockets send that url and the web server serve those image.